# reject internet-bound connections (from windows) without the wait?

Tags: windows, iptables

I have decided to cut off most access to the internet from my home network, since telemetry is just too popular now and I no longer trust most software to be on the internet.

So I have an iptables rule on my router/firewall that rejects outgoing internet-bound data (with some exceptions preceding it).

With this rule, windows hosts (XP and 7 at least) seem to ignore any ICMP host-unreachable or net-unreachable packets, and instead keep trying to connect for 30s or so before giving up.

Is there a way to get connection attempts to fail quickly on these OS's?

Comment: It may not be the host that's ignoring the ICMP messages, but the Application. depending on the application runtime, the app bound to a TCP port to establish a connection, so it won't get ICMP messages (ICMP is a different L3 protocol) unless the runtime supports that kind of network exception and the program includes logic for it. The application is not necessarily spending the time retrying but instead waiting on response traffic from the remote service until a timeout has elapsed.  It may retry after the timeout occurs, but that would likely indicate a longer wait.

Comment: @Frank: The app doesn't need to get actual ICMP messages, the OS can do that and just translate it into direct error codes. For example on Linux you do get ENETUNREACH or even EACCESS from calling connect(), entirely because of ICMP errors received. I've always been confused as to why Windows doesn't do the same, although I had found some mentions that it might be anti-DoS "feature" (protecting against _spoofed_ ICMPs)..